# MSSQL Null Query Plan

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am executing below Query to get cached execution plan details. I am seeing that Query_Plan for some of the stored procedure is null . what could be the reason ? does it mean my query requires improvement ?

```
       SELECT plan_handle,usecounts, cacheobjtype, objtype, size_in_bytes, text,query_plan
         FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans 
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(plan_handle)
  CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_query_plan(plan_handle)
        WHERE objtype = 'Proc' 
     ORDER BY usecounts DESC;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under certain conditions no output is returned in the `query_plan` column, as mentioned on [BOL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189747.aspx):

> Under the following conditions, no Showplan output is returned in the
>   query_plan column of the returned table for **sys.dm_exec_query_plan**:

- If the query plan that is specified by using plan_handle has been evicted from the plan cache, the **query_plan** column of the returned table is null. For example, this condition may occur if there is a time delay between when the plan handle was captured and when it was used with **sys.dm_exec_query_plan**.
- Some Transact-SQL statements are not cached, such as bulk operation statements or statements containing string literals larger than 8 KB in size. XML Showplans for such statements cannot be retrieved by using **sys.dm_exec_query_plan** unless the batch is currently executing because they do not exist in the cache.
- If a Transact-SQL batch or stored procedure contains a call to a user-defined function or a call to dynamic SQL, for example using EXEC (string), the compiled XML Showplan for the user-defined function is not included in the table returned by **sys.dm_exec_query_plan** for the batch or stored procedure. Instead, you must make a separate call to **sys.dm_exec_query_plan** for the plan handle that corresponds to the user-defined function.